# ionic side menu animation from slide in to slide over

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have 0 knowledge about css so this might be very simple for you folks. I am trying to change ionic side menu animation from slide in to slide over. Basically, when user clicks on the side menu, content should not move and side menu should be on top of it. Reason I am trying to achieve this is because i have a cordova google map plugin which will not move when side menu pushes the content and there it looks really ugly.

Any suggestion/solution

Comment: i am using ionic default animation.

Comment: you solved this problem?. I had the same problem and the only way that I find was make my own CSS like any web, but I lost the Animation effects.

Comment: @cmarrero01 I couldn't figure out so I went with the default animation. Bottom solution didn't work for me

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-ion-drawer. I find it posting on the oficial forum of ionic.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to made your own menu.
Basically you make a div with an absolute position and toggle it.

I made a simple jsfiddle so you can try this. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukabers/un610bou/)

```
.mySide{position: absolute; left: 0; width: 40%; z-index: 100;}
```

Hope it helps.